# Open PDF (at a precise point)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, pdf, razor, hyperlink

i would like to retrieve a pdf created by me from a link that can be visited in my website developed with Asp.NET MVC 4 , but i would like that the pdf would start from a precise point.

For example, if pdf has got the  following structure:

1) Index
2) Chapter I
2) Chapter II
3) Chapter III
4) Conclusion

I would like that, when opening the link, it starts from the page when Chapter I starts.
I don't want to have a dependency with pages because the document can grow so page numbers can change.

How can i do that?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't think this is possible unfortunately. You're asking the pdf viewer (could be any pdf viewer the user chooses to install) to accept a parameter that will determine which page number to open the document on. There are an arbitrary amount of pdf viewers, none of which I know expose such functionality. If what you're ultimately wanting to do is ONLY show that point onwards, you could manipulate the pdf with a library such as aspose or itextsharp and offer a different 'sub' pdf of the original based on which chapter you want the user to land on.

Answer (score 1):

http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf

I solved by using open parameters (I set bookmarks with Microsoft Word, then save as pdf maintaing bookmarks and i open pdf using site//name.pdf#Bookmarkname .

Thanks!